# "incomplete dynamic bit lengths tree" exception is happened on H2Database

Tags: zip, h2

Our product use H2DB to share our product information for all clients.
These days one client report that they can't use our system with below error message.

I move that file to other server, and it work fine.

Is anyone know this issue ?

05/02/2011 16:17:27,581 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 90031, SQLState: 90031
05/02/2011 16:17:27,581 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] IO Exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete dynamic bit lengths tree; zip:/home/ads/RealMedia/ads/OpenAd/RMFoundry/H2DB/OasRM_H2.zip!/OasRM.data.db [90031-72]

05/02/2011 16:17:27,582 INFO  [STDOUT] org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [XXXXXXX(It is SQL )]; SQL state [90031]; error code [90031]; IO Exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete dynamic bit lengths tree; zip:YYYYY/H2DB/Database.zip!/Data1.data.db [90031-72]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete dynamic bit lengths tree; zip:YYYYY/H2DB/Database.zip!/Data1.data.db [90031-72]

05/02/2011 16:17:27,585 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
05/02/2011 16:17:27,586 ERROR [[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
05/02/2011 16:17:27,587 ERROR [[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
05/02/2011 16:21:02,367 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
05/02/2011 16:21:55,580 ERROR [[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)

Answer (score 0):

If it works on one computer but not the other, it might be a problem of the JVM. See also [this issue report for the Sun JVM](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4188883).

By the way, you are using H2 version 1.0.72 (the build number is included in the error code, [90031-72]) which is quite old. Did you consider upgrading to a more recent version of H2?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I also agree your opinion, it could be a bug on JVM. But above link is too old and it is difference message with our. ( We showing that "imcomplete dynamic bit lengths tree" ).

Comment: I agree the JVM issue is old, however I don't know the JVM version you / your customer uses. The message is different than in the JVM issue, but you will find your message in one of the comments of the JVM issue. I just don't think it's a bug in H2, because the problem doesn't occur on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

I find a reason of it.

Actually we update database file regularly , and after that we reestablish JDBC connection to new file.
Unfortunately , error happened during reestablish JDBC connection, so JDBC connection isn't refreshed.

That is main reason of it.

Thanks Thomas to answer my question.
It is very helpful for us to find a reason.